# Como importar packages existentes em um mesmo diretório em uma aplicação NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Olá, estou criando uma solução que foi distribuída em múltiplos projetos e que contém recursos compartilhados entre si. Minha solução é desenvolvida no geral em NodeJS juntamente com outras soluções e até o momento tem essa estrutura:

```
<solution>
  | - .gitignore
  | - client   // ~> app em React UI para browser
  | - core     // -> artefatos comuns entre todos os projetos
  | - server   // ~> api
  | - database // ~> camada de DAO
  | - mobile   // ~> app em React Native para mobile
  | - desktop  // -> app em React Desktop para ser instalado localmente
```

Cada diretório será um projeto específico (`package.json`) tendo seus tests, src e dist. Preciso importar o pacote `core` nos outros projetos para que eu possa compartilhar classes, scripts e outros elementos. O que preciso fazer para que eu possa importar o core nos outros pacotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa montar um [Monorepo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monorepo).

As ferramentas que vão te ajudar nisso são as seguintes:

- [Yarn Workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/)
- [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/)

**Sobre o Yarn Workspaces**

O Yarn Workspaces serve para gerenciar projetos com múltiplos projetos, suas principais funcionalidades são:

1. Instalar dependencias na root de um projeto principal e permitir que
   os seus sub-projetos o utilizem. Isso ajuda muito a manter as
   dependencias compartilhadas atualizadas e remover código duplicado de
   cada projeto.
2. Cria links simbolicos entre as dependencias para que elas seja
   utilizadas entre si.

**Sobre o Lerna**

Antes de o Yarn Workspaces ser lançado, o Lerna era utilizado para este tipo arquitetura, que agora, o Yarn Workspaces faz de uma forma mais "nativa" por ser diretamente no gerenciador de pacotes.

Agora o Lerna é utilizado como uma interface entre o Yarn Workspace e os nossos projetos, ao executar alguns comandos do Lerna como para linkar dependências por exemplo, ele utiliza o Workspaces por de baixo dos panos. Além disso, o Lerna também utiliza o Git para nos ajudar a resolver alguns problemas, como de publicação.

Falando de forma muito resumida ele executa comandos em cada um dos projetos de uma só vez, por exemplo:

```
lerna publish
```

Vai criar uma tag no Git incrementando a versão no(s) package(s).json que foram alterados e publicar em algum NPM Registry

```
lerna run build
```

Vai executar yarn build em todos os projetos.

Comment: fantástico... era exatamente isso que eu estava pensando em fazer... estou acostumado a trabalhar com as "solutions" que existem em projetos c# e gostaria de fazê-lo com nodejs... isso facilita muito o desenvolvimento além de uma melhor organização, controle de código e uma pá de vantagens ainds rsrs.